# How to check column and row only for a certain number on the grid 2d list

Tags: python

So say for example this is the grid

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
    ----------------------------
 1 |[[0, 0, 6, 9, 5, 8, 0, 3, 2], 
 2 | [0, 7, 5, 6, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0], 
 3 | [0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0], 
 4 | [0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 9, 0, 7, 1], 
 5 | [8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3], 
 6 | [3, 0, 0, 1, 7, 0, 0, 5, 0], 
 7 | [5, 6, 7, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3], 
 8 | [9, 1, 7, 0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0], 
 9 | [3, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

How would I be able to find all numbers in only in a specific row and column.
For example, the x and y coordinate of (6,7), which is 4, I wanted to know all the numbers in only that row and column that are not 0.
So the answer would be [8,1,6,9,4,4,5,6,7,2,3]. There can duplicates and order does not matter. So how would I find a specific spot and a grid and check for the number in it's column and row and have it put into the list?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please add those things also in your question! And if you found anything while doing doing research about it, also add those.

Comment: use `numpy` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy
 

l= [[0, 0, 6, 9, 5, 8, 0, 3, 2], 
    [0, 7, 5, 6, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0], 
    [0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 9, 0, 7, 1], 
    [8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3], 
    [3, 0, 0, 1, 7, 0, 0, 5, 0], 
    [5, 6, 7, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3], 
    [9, 1, 7, 0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0], 
    [3, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

# initializing list
def get_coordinates(array,row,col):
    x=[j for j in array[ : , col]if j!=0]
    y=[i for i in array[row] if i!=0]
    return x+y
# converting list to array
arr = numpy.array(l)
print(get_coordinates(arr,6,5))
```